# Log in form with restricted-country.tpl and Geolocation with Prestashop 1.6

Tags: ajax, forms, authentication, geolocation, prestashop-1.6

I got to build a log in form on restricted-country.tpl to access my website.

The form and the ajax call work great but it's impossible to call the php script 'cause a 503 error due to geolocation.

The script is in "controllers/front/".

Anybody knows how to grant access to the script or knows an area where I could put it and access it passing through the 503?
Or maybe call it in an other way?

(It's important that the log in form use Geolocation by ip)

**Here is the form :**

> ```
>    <form class="form-signin col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="everaccess_form">
>       <label for="password" style="color:#FFF;">{l s='Mot de passe'}</label><br/>
>             <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Identifiant" required>
>             <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
>             <input type="hidden" id="IP" name="IP" class="form-control" value="">
>             <input type="hidden" id="shop" name="shop" class="form-control" value="{$cart->id_shop}">
>           <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="width:22.5%;" value="{l s='Se connecter'}" />
>       <br/><hr>
>     </form>
> ```

**Here is the ajax call :**

```
form.submit(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path_url+'/controllers/front/verif.php',
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(jsonData) {
      if (jsonData == 'OK'){
        console.log('Correct logins');
        location.reload();
      } else {
        console.log(jsonData);
      }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Status: " + textStatus);
      alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Here is the script :**

```
if (Tools::getIsset('password') || Tools::getIsset('login') || Tools::getIsset('IP') || Tools::getIsset('shop')) {

    $password = Tools::getValue('password');
        $login = Tools::getValue('login');
        $allowedUsers = EverCommission::getAllAgentLogin();
        foreach ($allowedUsers as $user => $mail) {
          $users[$user] = $mail['email'];
        }
            if ($password == Configuration::get('EVERCOM_COM_PASS') && in_array($login, $users)) {

                //Separator
                $separator = "\n";
                $idShop = Tools::getValue('shop');

                //Geolocalisation whitelist
                $whitelist = Configuration::get('PS_GEOLOCATION_WHITELIST');
                $WhiteListIp = Tools::getValue('IP');
                $New_WhiteList = $whitelist . $separator . $WhiteListIp;

                //Temp whitelist
                $Old_Temp_WhiteList = Configuration::get('PS_TEMP_WHITELIST');
                $New_Temp_WhiteList = $Old_Temp_WhiteList . $separator . $WhiteListIp;

                //Updating values
                Configuration::updateValue('PS_TEMP_WHITELIST', $New_Temp_WhiteList);
                Configuration::updateValue('PS_GEOLOCATION_WHITELIST', $New_WhiteList, false, null, $idShop);
                Configuration::updateValue('PS_GEOLOCATION_WHITELIST', $New_WhiteList, false, null, 'NULL');
                $return = 'OK';
            } else {
                $return = 'Wrong';
            }
        echo Tools::jsonEncode($return);
} else {
        $return = 'ID or Password not set using Ajax';
        echo Tools::jsonEncode($return);
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you check your error log files and post any related error here ?

Comment: Ajax posts these errors : 
- Status: error
- Error: temporarily overloaded

Comment: Ok can you check apache error logs ?

Comment: Here is what I found : 
"POST /prestashop//controllers/front/verif.php HTTP/1.1" 503 2873

Comment: That is a log from the access.log file not error.log.

Comment: Is your site online (witch hosting privder ?) or local on your machine ?

Comment: The site where I test is local on my machine. In error.log, there is nothing related to that error but maybe you'll find something : 
`[Thu Jan 07 15:23:07.539311 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 15802] AH00163: Apache/2.4.17 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1q PHP/5.6.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 07 15:23:07.539361 2016] [core:notice] [pid 15802] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'`
(This is the last two lines of error.log)

Answer (score 0):

Since your ajax call returns `Error: temporarily overloaded`, you might have a `memory_limit` problem on your configuration.

1. Open your shop BackOffice
2. Go to `advanced parameters` > `Informations`
3. Check that the memory limit is over or equal to 128M

If the `memory_limit` is lower. You should edit your `php.ini` file.

Comment: The `memory_limit` is equal to 128M.

Comment: Try to echo some text at each lines `echo('test1'); ... echo('test2');` to see how far the script goes before crashing. Or by placing a `die('test') at different lines to see where it crashes.

Comment: Thank you for you help @Florian

The script doesn't crach. Sorry my bad english, I may explained wrong. 
I activated the geolocation to restrict access to the website. (the script works well when geolocation is inactive)

So, from the template "restricted-country.tpl", I have to call the php script but geolocation logicaly doesn't let access to it. I'm looking for a way or an area to call it passing through the geolocation restriction.
Sorry my bad english again.